# Rspec test a method in a simple script

Tags: ruby, rspec

Surely a really easy question for someone, but I can't figure out how to test a method in a simple Ruby script that has methods but no classes.

A very simple method:

```
def s2hm(s)
  "%sh %sm" % [s / 3600, s / 60 % 60].map { |t| t.to_s }
end
```

Since it's just a simple script, I don't have any classes, and all documentation out there seems to only talk about using Rspec to unit test classes.

So in Rspec, I have presumably will have something like:

```
describe '#s2hm' do
  it 'should convert seconds to hours and minutes' do
    ... # what goes here
  end
end
```

Could someone advise on how I'd complete that describe block?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: call your method and make sure the return value is what you expect it to be with a known input.  http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames

Comment: @KorreyD I've seen that but it doesn't really help me.  I want to say "expect the function s2hm when passed '12345678' to return "21h 18m".  I've tried every combination of syntax I've been able to find over the last 4 hours and nothing's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with something like this, I got it to work using:

```
describe '#s2hm' do
  it 'should convert seconds to hours and minutes' do
    expect(s2hm(7320)).to eq '2h 2m'
  end

  it 'should convert seconds to hours and minutes' do
    expect(s2hm(7200)).to eq '2h 0m'
  end

  it 'should convert seconds to hours and minutes' do
    expect(s2hm(12345678)).to eq '3429h 21m'
  end
end
```